# Ruby Map with Ancestry

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following this railscast episode on using ancestry:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/262-trees-with-ancestry

I'm not understanding the map method.  Could someone explain how "sub_messages" works?

```
def nested_messages(messages)
  messages.map do |message, **sub_messages**|
    render(message) + content_tag(:div, nested_messages(sub_messages), :class => "nested_messages")
  end.join.html_safe
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `map` on a hash, it iterates through the hash and (in your example), assigns the key to `message` and the value to `sub_messages`.